# Derivation of $\operatorname{tgh}^{-1}(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)=\operatorname{arctanh}(x)={1\over 2}\left(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\right)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I think I posted dupe post.

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{\tanh^{-1}(x)={1\over 2}\ln\left({1+x\over 1-x}\right)={1\over 2}\left(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\right)}~~\text{with}~~\left(\left|x\right|<1\right)
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\text{The above eqns can be used in path for soln of}
\int{1\over e^x+e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

I have 2 doubts about red-marked eqns.

1. How$~\tanh^{-1}(x)={1\over 2}\ln\left(1+x\over{1-x}\right)~$be obtained?
2. I think the condition$~\left|x\right|<1~$is too strict for the indefinte integral problem at 2nd row.

Comment: Solve $y=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$ ($=\tanh x$) for $x$.

Comment: I think I derived the equation from your advice.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I got $~\operatorname{arctan}\left(e^x\right)+C~$ using your idea :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
y&={e^{2x}-1\over e^{2x}+1}
\\y\left(e^{2x}+1\right)&=\left(e^{2x}-1\right)\\
y e^{2x}+y&=e^{2x}-1\\
e^{2x}\left(y-1\right)&=-(y+1)\\
e^{2x}&={-(y+1)\over(y-1)}\\
\ln\left(\exp\left(2x\right)\right)&=\ln\left({(1+y)\over(1-y)}\right)\\
2x&=\ln(1+y)-\ln(1-y)\\&=\ln\left({1+y\over 1-y}\right)\\
x&={1\over 2}\ln\left({1+y\over 1-y}\right)\\
\operatorname{tgh}^{-1}(y)&=x\\&={1\over 2}\ln\left({1+y\over 1-y}\right)\end{align}$$

Since$~y=\operatorname{tgh}(x)~$is held,$~-1<y<1~$is held for$~-\infty<x<\infty~$.

And from the initial condition of rightmost-red-marked-inequality, we can simply replace$~\operatorname{tgh}^{-1}(y)={1\over 2}\ln\left({1+y\over 1-y}\right)~$by$~\operatorname{tgh}^{-1}(x)={1\over 2}\ln\left({1+x\over 1-x}\right)~~\text{with}~~\left|x\right|<1~$